# blacklisting a maven repository

Tags: java, maven

When I run an integration test for my project, it is trying to search in a repo that is being pulled transitively and I need to wait for time out. I blacklisted that repo like this.

```
   <repository>
        <id>seacrh-snapshots</id>
        <name>Exodus Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo URL/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
   </repository>
```

but it is still pulling this repo when I run the IT test:

```
Downloading: URL repo/maven-metadata.xml
```

Is there anything else that need to be changed?

Comment: Where have you blacklisted the repo? Only in your POM? Maybe you have this repository also in your settings.xml.

Comment: I have added that in setting.xml too, it is still pulling that repo.

Comment: Run maven with the option x (mvn -X) to see which setting-files maven is reading, maybe Maven is reading still another configuration file.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend to use a Maven Repository Manager such as Nexus. It will help you to get stable and reproducible builds with Maven. You can disable Repositories there (or Nexus can handle this for you as well).

http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html

http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html

Answer (score 3):

Normally, when maven runs it goes to fetch artifacts in the following order

1. it check your local .m2/repositories folder
2. if it can't find the artifact then it reads your pom / parent pom/ super Pom / user level setting.xml/ global setting.xml - in that order to find external repositories to download the artifacts from, usually these repo are either directly from the internet (like the pre-configured default maven repositories) or local private repo managers(like nexus, Artifactory).
3. Maven will execute the repo as in the order in which they are declared.

First of all, check your project effective-pom that nothing else is overriding your configuration. either in the terminal by typing mvn help:effective-pom on the project root dir or easily in eclipse "effective pom" view of your pom.

Otherwise, it's a good use-case for you to consider installing local repository manager as you would not always need to fetch externally your third party dependencies everytime you run maven. 
i would recommend Artifactory much better than the nexus.